# TypeError: this.state.persons.map is not a function Thanks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and only understand the basics. I got this project from someone to look at, but I'm scratching my head since morning with this problem:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.state.persons.map is not a function.
```

Please, if you can try to try to go over it in easy but in under the hood way. Thank You!

```
import React, { useState, Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Person from './Person/Person';
import person from './Person/Person';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

class App extends Component {
   state =
   {
    persons:[
    {id: '123', name:'Max', age: 28 },
    {id: '124',name:'Mari', age: 26 },
    {id: '125',name: 'laly', age: 20 }

  ],
  showPersons: false 
  }

nameChangeHandler=( event,id ) =>
{ const personIndex = this.state.persons.findIndex(p=>{
  return p.id === id;
});

const person = {...this.state.persons[personIndex]
};
person.name=event.target.value;
const persons=[ ...this.state.persons];
persons[personIndex]=person;
  this.setState(
    {
      persons:person
    }
  )
}

togglePersonHandler =  ()=>
{
const doesShow = this.state.showPersons;
this.setState ({showPersons: !doesShow});
}

deletePersonHandler= (personIndex)=> {
//const persons = this.state.persons;
const persons = [...this.state.persons]
persons.splice(personIndex,1);
this.setState({persons:persons});
}
  render()
{
  const style ={
    backgroundColor:'yellow',
    font:'inherit',
    border:'1px solid blue',
    padding:'8px',
    cursor:'pointer'
  };

  let persons=null;
  if (this.state.showPersons){
   persons= (
   <div>
    {this.state.persons.map((person,index)=> {return <Person click={() => this.deletePersonHandler(index)}
    name = {person.name} 
    age = {person.age} 
    key={person.id}
    change ={(event) => this.nameChangeHandler(event,person.id)}
     />
     })};
  </div>)

  };

 return (

  <div className="App">
      <h1>Hi This is react App</h1>
      <button style={style} onClick={this.togglePersonHandler}> Toggle Persons</button>

       {persons}


    </div>
  ); 
    }
    }

export default App;
```

Comment: In `nameChangeHandler`, you have a typo. It should be `this.setState({ persons:persons })` with an additional `s`. Or just `this.setState({ persons })` to use the shorthand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error lies here :

```
nameChangeHandler=( event,id ) =>
{ const personIndex = this.state.persons.findIndex(p=>{
  return p.id === id;
});

const person = {...this.state.persons[personIndex]
};
person.name=event.target.value;
const persons=[ ...this.state.persons];
persons[personIndex]=person;
  this.setState(
    {
      persons:person    ------------ > You are assigning a single object to a list in your state, so your map is giving an error, it must be {persons: persons}
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see `___ is not a function`, try looking at whatever the function is referring to.

In this case you're using `map`, which is an Array function. So you need to verify if the array (the thing at the left of the dot) is actually an array.

The function call:

`this.state.persons.map`

The array you need to pay attention to is `persons`. So try to look for the place in the code where `persons` is not getting recognized an array.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here, you are assigning and object to state instead of an array. in the funcion **nameChangeHandler**.

```
  this.setState(
    {
      persons:person
    }
  )
```

With a simple console inside the render or just watching it inside the Components Menu in the browser you can notice it bro.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It probably happens here, where you replace the array of persons with a single person:

```
    this.setState(
      {
        persons: person
      }
    )
```

You probably want to do this instead:

```
this.setState({persons});
```